# Recommended 3D camera settings and model sizes for an FPS

Tags: 3d, camera, first-person-shooter

I'm making a simple FPS and I can't decide on the size of my models and my camera settings. Could someone please recommend a good combination of:

- **camera field of view**
- **near and far planes**
- **model proportions** (such as 1 unit = 1 meter)

so that the game looks realistic enough and the numbers are easy to work with?

**EDIT:** I know I can use whatever dimensions I want, but I'd like to know what is most commonly found in games.

Answer (score 4):

- **camera FOV** - near to human eye fov -> 60 degrees, but you can play with that
- **near and far planes** - near plane is usualy 0.1 distance, but far plane have to be as near as possible to gain the best depth buffer accurancy. Same for near plane, it should be as far as possible.
- **model proportions** - use whatever you like. But meters are just fine.

Answer (score 2):

For wide-screens you'd want a field of view around 1 (equal to 90 degrees of horizontal vision). Experiment a bit to find out what looks good for a default, but do give players the means to adjust it.

Near and far planes should ideally be as restricted as possible without clipping, but given a 24 bit Z-buffer it's not very important to restrict them tightly.

You can use what scale you like, it won't make any practical difference. 1 unit ~= 1 meter is probably the most common, but it's not like you are going to run into issues if a designer use a different scale than the game, it takes virtually no effort to rescale a model as needed.